# Constant lookup operator task in Rubymonk

Tags: ruby, module, scope

I'm plodding through Rubymonk's Ruby course and came across a task flagged as unsolved. I can's solve it either.

It goes like this:

> If you prepend a constant with `::` without a parent, the scoping happens on the topmost level. In this exercise, change `push` to return `10` as per `A = 10` in the topmost level, outside the `Kata` module.

```
module Kata
  A = 5
  module Dojo
    B = 9
    A = 7

    class ScopeIn
      def push
        A
      end
    end
  end
end

A = 10
```

So I put `::A`, it returned `10`, but Rubymonk doesn't let me pass. It tells me in the output window that

```
Kata::Dojo::ScopeIn.new.push
```

should return `10`. This completely confused me because I thought my code should return `10` **outside the `Kata` module**. And

```
Kata::Dojo::ScopeIn.new.push
```

is within the `Kata` module, isn't it?

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Task is at the bottom of [the page](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/35-modules/lessons/80-modules-as-namespaces#solution4151).

Answer (score 2):

Yep, the wording is a little confusing. What they wanted you to do was:

```
::Kata::Dojo::A = 10
```

> change `push` to return `10` as per `A = 10` in the topmost level, outside the `Kata` module

What they meant by this is you should change the value of the constant `A` that will be looked up in the `ScopeIn#push` method, but you are not allowed change it where it was defined. Instead, you have to change it **from** the topmost level